# How to remove empty cells in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to remove the empty cells in excel of thousands of rows and columns can anyone help me on this? The values of the excel should be in order.

**Sample Input:**

[image]

**Desired Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is essentially the same as @Tony's, but it doesn't use any extra cells.

```
Dim counter As Integer, i As Integer
counter = 1
For i = 1 To 10
    If Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then
        Cells(counter, 1) = Cells(i, 1)
        counter = counter + 1
    End If
Next i
For i = counter To 10
    Cells(i, 1) = ""
Next i
```

There is no chance of losing data, as there are blanks in the original, so that `counter` is always less than or equal to `i`. The last `for..next` loop clears any remaining visible previous data.

Comment: Thank you for reply JMP, It works only on first column not for the second column.

Comment: You have to change the '1' in all the `Cells()` to a '2' to do that, and you might need to change the '10' in the loops as well to the column length.

Answer (score 1):

Press Alt F11 to run a script as a macro.
This website offers some insight that may be helpful.
https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/delete-blank-cells.html

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is:

- Select column A:B
- Go to ribbon > <kbd>Start</kbd>
- Under editing > <kbd>Search & Select</kbd>
- Click > <kbd>Select Special</kbd>
- Click > <kbd>Blanks</kbd>

Now all your empty cells should be selected

- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> and shift cells up.